# Gradle implementation project throws exception

Tags: gradle

I have this hierarchy to my project:

```
- project
  - project-server
    - build.gradle
    - gradle.properties
    - settings.gradle    
  - project-client
    - build.gradle
    - gradle.properties
    - settings.gradle
  - build.gradle
  - gradle.properties
  - settings.gradle
```

In the parent build.gradle file I added these lines:

```
project(':project-client') {
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':project-server')
    }
}
```

and I am getting:

> What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'project'.
>
> > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':project-client'] on object of type
> >     org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

This is my entire build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

println(subprojects.each {it -> it.name})

project(':project-client') {
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':project-server')
    }
}

allprojects {
    group = 'com.test'

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
          //local nexus config
        }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

subprojects {
    version = {version}
}
```

This is the setting.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'project'

include 'project-server', 'project-client'
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`implementation` configuration is added by the [`java` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.htm).

You've applied `java` plugin only for the root project, in the provided `build.gradle`. Your `:project-client` subproject does not inherit plugins from it's parent (root), so the `java` plugin was not applied to `:project-client` project.

That's why it "could not find method `implementation()` for arguments...". Make sure to apply `java` plugin to subprojects.